# How to pipe the result of wget to tar

Tags: bash, curl, wget, tar

I'm trying to create a command that would download the latest .gz file and install on my container in Dockerfile. I came up with this but I can't seem to get it working.

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/fullstorydev/grpcurl/releases/latest | grep 'linux_arm64.tar.gz' | cut -d : -f 2,3 | tr -d \" | wget -qi - | sudo tar -C /usr/local/bin -xz;
```

I always get this error

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: The first part of the pipe is selecting two files. The input to `tar` should be a single file.

Comment: I think you only want to select the `browser_download_url` line, not the `name` line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like this:

```
file=$(
  curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/fullstorydev/grpcurl/releases/latest |
    jq -r '.assets | .[] | select(.browser_download_url | contains("linux_arm64")) .browser_download_url'
)
wget -O- "$file" | tar zxvf - | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/grpcurl
```

---

See https://github.com/stedolan/jq

Comment: Tested script OK. Post edited accordingly.

Comment: Made rollback due to a bug

Answer (score -1):

your grep outputs to

```bash
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/fullstorydev/grpcurl/releases/latest | grep 'linux_arm64.tar.gz' | cut -d : -f 2,3 | tr -d \"

grpcurl_1.8.8_linux_arm64.tar.gz, 
https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl/releases/download/v1.8.8/grpcurl_1.8.8_linux_arm64.tar.gz
```

I am no expert in bash or piping but adding another grep would fix the issue

```bash
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/fullstorydev/grpcurl/releases/latest | grep 'linux_arm64.tar.gz' | grep https | cut -d : -f 2,3 | tr -d \"

 https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl/releases/download/v1.8.8/grpcurl_1.8.8_linux_arm64.tar.gz
```

so the fixed command looks like:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/fullstorydev/grpcurl/releases/latest | grep 'linux_arm64.tar.gz' | grep https | cut -d : -f 2,3 | tr -d \" | wget -qi - | sudo tar -C /usr/local/bin -xz;
```

Comment: Don't use `grep` to parse JSON, thanks